# Accordion em Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, accordion

*Olá boa tarde / noite*

*Sou novo com c#, Galera alguém aí tem uma ideia de como conseguiria o efeito accordion no Windows Form igual no HTML utilizando jquery*

Comment: você quer fazer isso http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/r6eaw/12/ ? um toggle, digamos ?

Comment: Sim , mas em Windows Form usando C#

Comment: Não me refiro em usar Jquery + HTML,  eu citei  como exemplo

Comment: eu sei meu amigo que não é em jquery + html que você quer, é que eu conheço esse efeito accordion como toggle, só queria confirmar, beleza !?

Comment: É pode , tipo queria esse efeito , no form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa esse componente de Accordion p/ Windows Forms ele funciona muito bem:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416521/Easy-WinForms-Accordion-Control

Comment: Obrigado, mas eu já consegui isso,  na verdade eu queria algo semelhante ao "Expander" digo um elemento que ao eu clicar ele vai se expandir mostrando conteúdos dentro dele.

Utilizei um painel, a classe Timer, então adicionei um evento ao painel que quando eu clicasse instanciava o timer, e o timer acionava uma outra função várias vezes, que incrementa o tamanho do painel por exemplo em 10 pxs na velocidade X,

Desse jeito eu determinava o tamanho que eu queria , quando ele alcançasse o tamanho desejado eu parava.